# I am using Selenium to try to login to websites and I am getting this error "xxx didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Tags: python, selenium, django-views

Here is my code:

def loginToShipstation(request):

```
url = "https://ss.shipstation.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/Robert Woods/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
x = HttpResponse
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id("btn-login").click()
```

It opens the browser and fills in the text boxes but errors out because of the None Httpresponse. How can I get around this?

Comment: Your view needs to return a http response, so for example `return HttpResponse()`.

Comment: Thanks Willem, that worked.